# How to write xpath for getting Child node and it's attribute?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have scenario where I have stored all parent node "//td" in list and Now I need to fetch details of child node of each element of list. Here is my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();

    WebElement Calendertable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tbody"));

    List<WebElement> Date = Calendertable.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    System.out.println(Date.size());

    for( WebElement e : Date) {

            System.out.println(e.findElement(By.xpath(".//a")).getAttribute("class"));

        }
```

[xpath details of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ygcV.png)

I need to get detail of all child of "td" node. I have written code but it is not working. It is throwing "NoSuchElementException:" for ".//a" element.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because some `<td>` cells (namely in the beginning and end of table, where there're no dates, have no `a` sub-tag, e.g.:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
```

So you could resolve it by checking that `td` has no `unselectable` or `disabled` class:

```
if(!e.getAttribute("class").contains("disabled")) {
  System.out.println(
      e.findElement(By.xpath(".//a")).getAttribute("class"));
    }
```

But even better: instead of searching multiple times, you could search once just for elements you care about (`a` inside `td`):

```
List<WebElement> aInDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tbody//td/a"));

for( WebElement a : aInDate) { 
    System.out.println(a.getAttribute("class")); }
```

Comment: Thanks lots. Your this statement "I think the reason is because some <td> cells (namely in the beginning and end of table, where there're no dates, have no a sub-tag, e.g.:"   Has resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fetch details of child node of each element within the list, try to create the list with the exact child nodes of your interest and then extract the `text` out of the elements as follows :

```
List<WebElement> Date = Calendertable.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//tbody//tr//td/a[@class='ui-state-default']"));
System.out.println(Date.size());
for( WebElement e : Date) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. You don't have to loop through all the cells and look for the one you want and then click it. You can create a locator using XPath that will get you exactly the day you want first time. When I write code for functionality I'm likely to use over and over (like selecting a day), I generally write a function so that it can be easily reused.

The code

```
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
chooseDay(11);
```

The function

```
public static void chooseDay(int day)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[.='" + day + "']")).click();
}
```

Basically you call the `chooseDay()` function and pass in the day you want clicked. The function look for an `A` tag that contains the day you chose and clicks it.

This is working code.